# SSH login as root fails, but I'm sure I entered the right password

Tags: ssh, root

What am I missing?  I change the root password on a unix machine, then try to log in with that password.  `PasswordAuthentication` is set to `yes` in `sshd_config` and the `sshd` daemon has been restarted.  This behavior happens whether I log in remotely or locally:

```
root@ip-10-0-0-155:~# passwd
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
root@ip-10-0-0-155:~# ssh root@127.0.0.1
root@127.0.0.1's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@127.0.0.1's password:
```

Comment: Some systems do not allow `root` login have to verified that?

Comment: make sure of your ip's which you have changed the password and trying to re-login are the same ip's.

Comment: Check root login permission: `grep -i permitroot /etc/sshd_config`.

Comment: This is not necessarily a good idea...

Comment: Perhaps someone can clarify this: I found that a password that contained a `@` always failed (for three different clean installs) but an identical password that used a `!` instead worked OK

Answer (score 13):

Check this file: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and search for the line:

`PermitRootLogin no`

replace it by:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Comment: Tough if you can't log in as root - having the same problem

Comment: This is the solution, but security wise, there are probably some better options..

Answer (score 2):

You may get more informations on the error by reading the auth.log

In my case, there was another security blocking inside `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` , one of these lines :

- AllowGroups
- AllowUsers
- DenyGroups
- DenyUsers

Fix them, and then `service sshd restart`

Comment: +1 for telling people to look at the `auth.log`

Comment: Could be `/var/log/secure` on REL-type systems.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it.

My keyboards were not configured in the same manner between an `ssh` console and the server's keyboard. The key <kbd>+</kbd> on my numpad was, in fact, the <kbd>=</kbd>; but I never find out why.

Check if you enter the same characteres.

Answer (score 0):

You are logging in to `localhost` with `ssh`.  This is usually not necessary and may carry some overhead.  Try

```
su -
```

in a terminal and enter the password.